# How can I impersonate another user with Passport.js in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

Using Passport.js in Node, is there a way for me to allow one user to impersonate another?  eg. as an Administrator in the application, I want to be able to log in as another user, without knowing their password.

Most simply, I would be satisfied if I could change the serialized user data (user ID) so when `deserializeUser` is called it will just assume the identity of the alternate user.  I've tried replacing the value at `req._passport.session.user` and the value at `req.session.passport.user` but the net effect is just that my session seems to become invalid and Passport logs me out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Passport provides a [`req.logIn`](http://passportjs.org/docs/login) method in case you want to do the authentication manually. You can use it to login any user even regardless of authentication.

Here's how you can use it. Have the Admin login normally, who'll have an `isAdmin` flag set.

Then place a middleware before `passport.authenticate` in your login route. This will login the **new** user based only on their username, if the *currently* logged in user `isAdmin`.

```javascript
app.post('/login',

    function forceLogin(req, res, next) {
        if (!req.user.isAdmin) return next(); // skip if not admin
        User.findOne({
            username: req.body.username    // < entered username
        }, function(err, user) {
            // no checking for password
            req.logIn(user);
            res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
        });
    },

    passport.authenticate('local'),
    function(req, res) {
        res.redirect('/users/' + req.user.username);
    }
);
```

Comment: This is what I was missing!  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I have another way to impersonate, because:

- I didn't want to mess with internals of authentication/passport like
  session storage / logIn / etc. You must understand them really well
  and also they are prone to change so I'd say it's not an option for
  me.
- Also, I'd like to still be able to tell if action is made from
  superuser (impersonated) or normal user (not impersonated).

What I do is:

- Have a route for user with superadmin role to impersonate, like `/superadmin/impersonate?username=normaluser1` which sets `req.user.impersonated.userid = normaluser1.userid`
- Then I have a middleware, which checks if user is superadmin and is impersonated:

  if (req.user.isAdmin && req.user.impersonated) {
    req.user.userid = req.user.impersonated.userid;
  }

Also, I have found [this](https://auth0.com/docs/user-profile/user-impersonation#use-the-impersonation-api) to be a good article about user impersonation. Similar to my approach, and good for inspiration for building something similar.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is *basically*: no. The reason is this: the sessions library that is being used 99% of the time is signing the cookies, so if you tamper with the data the web server will reject it.

The way around this is to write your own passport authentication strategy that obviously doesn't do this, but I'm assuming you're talking about working with the built-in strategies here.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried creating a new strategy (my existing strategies are basically from this: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/authenticating-nodejs-applications-with-passport--cms-21619), but couldn't get it to work.  I assumed it was because I was trying to call passport's authenticate method while the user was already logged in.  How do I "reauthenticate" an already logged in user?

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly? The way to authenticate a user (at any time) is via passport.authenticate's middleware helper =) You can call this directly with a callback of your own if you want. This might be better for a new SO post though!

Comment: I disagree, but I fear I won't get an answer unless I do...  My original question is "how can one user impersonate another using Passport.js?"  The session discussion was only one way I thought *might* work, but apparently it won't.  I still don't have an answer to my original question.  Is there some other way to CHANGE the user that Passport thinks is logged in?

Comment: You can *change* the user passport thinks is logged in by generating a new session fresh on the server-side. This is the only way. You can then call passport.authenticate AGAIN.

Comment: Could you please provide example code or point me to somewhere that explains how to do this?